# When natural restriction map is an isomorphism for coherent cohomology?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a projective variety over a field $k$ with dimension $d$ and $U$ be an open subvariety of $X$. Suppose that $Z= X - U$ has $t$-dimension (for example: $Z$ be singular locus of $X$).

Is there an integer $q$ that depends on $d$ and $t$ such that for any coherent sheaf $\mathscr{F}$ on $X$, the natural restriction map

$$H^i (X,\mathscr{F}) \rightarrow H^i (U,\mathscr{F})$$

is an isomorphism for any $i\leq q$?

Comment: Absolutely not.

Comment: Think of the case where $U$ is affine...

Comment: Actually, I think this is a very reasonable question, even if the answer to the literal question is no. (One key issue: $\mathcal F$ might have small support, say even in $Z$, when the result is clearly false.) Large parts of SGA2 are about this type of question! (Basically the invariant you're looking for is the depth of $\mathcal F$ along $Z$.) I'm somewhat disappointed by the downvoting and unhelpful comments (especially for a new contributor, writing a very sensible question); for example, $U$ cannot be affine unless $t=d-1$.

Comment: @Peter Scholze: I was just pointing out what I think is the easiest case where the answer is negative. Hopefully it might help the OP to better formulate the question.

Comment: @abx But your scenario is not even giving a negative answer: If one restricts the question to smooth $X$ and vector bundles $\mathcal F$, then the answer becomes yes, with $q=d-t-2$. (In the context of the question, it was clear that $Z$ is supposed to have large codimension, so considering the situation that $U$ is affine is not the right thing to do.)

Comment: @Peter Scholze: What is this result on vector bundles you're talking about? Also, I may be wrong, but maybe abx example is for $X$ affine (not $U$) because then the question reduces to the isomorphism between the sections on $X$ and the sections on $U$ (I'm just trying to guess but actually I don't know).

Comment: I apologize for being ungenerous. Indeed, this can easily be made into an interesting question.